# zero stability of odes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help with the following problem?

Find the range of α for which the following method is zero stable.

$$y'=f(x,y)\\
f(a)=y_0 \\
y_{n+1}-(1+α) y_n + α y_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}h \left[(3-α) f_n-(1+α) f_{n-1}\right]$$
                                                        Where α is a parameter and $f_n=f(x_n,y_n)$

Thank you